# Как получить данные из json файла в pug шаблон?

Tags: javascript, html, json, pug

У меня есть файл dataset.json и файл index.pug В файле у меня есть переменная -let data. Как мне получить данные из файла dataset.json в переменную data в файл index.pug, где я буду в дальнейшем через цикл for или другим способом генерировать разметку. Мне не принципиально получить данные именно в переменную data, если есть другие варианты - тоже можно использовать.
Я сделал так. Создал файлик index.js где я обрабатываю свой json.

```
var pug = require('pug');
var fn = pug.compileFile('template.pug');
var locals = require('./dataset.json');
console.log(fn({
    name: locals
}));
console.log(locals)
```

В консоль выводится мой обработанный dataset.json файл.
Файл template.pug выглядит так

```
p #{name}'s Pug source code!
```

Tут возникает вопрос, а как мне сделать так, чтобы когда я вызываю сборку файла template.pug в консоли командой

```
pug template.pug
```

у меня перед этим вызвалась обработка моего index.js, где я присваиваю мой json в переменную name?

Comment: `pug -O dataset.json dev -P -w -o public` взять из папки dev, добавить переменные из dataset.json и сложить все в public

Comment: Не совсем понял, мне надо в конкретный файл в конкретное место. Файл dataset.json  у меня лежит в корневой директории.

Comment: Надеюсь полностью развёрнутый ответ удовлетворит ваши потребности, вообще такого за такого рода консультации я обычно беру 5 евреев в час. Во что входит полное обучение большинству нюансов программирования на выбранном вами языке/скрипте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаём папку `dev`, создаём папку `public`

В папке dev создаём файл `dev/index.pug` с таким вот содержимым.

```
html(lang=lang)
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1 Hello Wolrd!
    script
      | var data = !{JSON.stringify(locals)}
```

Далее в корне создаём файл `dataset.json` с таким вот содержимым.

```json
{
  "lang": "ruRU",
  "title": "Test Project"
}
```

Выполняем команду: `pug -O dataset.json dev -P -o public`

После которой в папке public появиться файл `public/index.html`

С таким вот содержимым

```html
<html lang="ruRU"><head>
    <title>Test Project</title>
</head><body>
    <h1>Hello Wolrd!</h1>
    <script>
        var data = {"lang":"ruRU","title":"Test Project","filename": "src//index.pug","complieDebug": true,"pretty": true}
    </script>
</body></html>
```